# How to create Class in DBContext and using generic to get data

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core

I want use generic to get data from my database.

So I created an interface to do so. I also create a class `DBRepo` to do inheritance for DB Model

```
public partial class UserAccount : DBRepo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class DBRepo
{
}
```

And this my Interface

```
public class DBServices
{     
        public interface IDBAction<TEntity> where TEntity : DBRepo
        {  
            List<TEntity> GetAllData(TEntity _entity);
        }

        public class dbCRUD<TEntity> : IDBAction<TEntity> where TEntity : DBRepo
        {
            private readonly CoreContext _db;
            private DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

            public dbCRUD(CoreContext _db)
            {
                this._db = _db;
                this.dbSet = _db.Set<TEntity>();
            }

            public List<TEntity> GetAllData(TEntity _entity)
            {
                var query = this.dbSet.Select(o=>o).ToList();
                return query;
            }
        }
    }
```

in main

```
ServiceCollection() provider = new ServiceCollection()
                                .AddScoped<IDBAction<DBRepo>, dbCRUD<DBRepo>>()
                                .AddScoped<CoreContext>()
                                .AddDbContext<CoreContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(SysBase.testConn1))
                                .BuildServiceProvider();
 provider.GetService<IDBAction<DBRepo>>().GetAllData(new UserAccount());
```

I get this error

> 'Cannot create a DbSet for 'DBRepo' because this type is not included in the model for the context.'

So, how to create `DBRepo` in `DBContext` or how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You must make your Context inherit from `DbContext`. You can [check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext) more details.

```
public class CoreContext : DbContext
{
    public CoreContext(DbContextOptions<CoreContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<UserAccount> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So, based on your code you must have something like this::
 
`public class CoreContext : DbContext
{
   public CoreContext(DbContextOptions<CoreContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<UserAccount> Users { get; set; }
}`

This is just an approximation, you didn't show your CoreContext code here so your class may have more behaviour already.
I'm going to edit my answer to have this code.